# Is there any way to set custom (aka user defined) file attributes on a file in Android?

Tags: java, android, file-attributes

I need to set user defined attributes for 2 reasons, 1- to mark encrypted files, 2- implementing a tag system like MacOS' Finder has.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Files.setAttribute(
    Paths.get("/storage/emulated/0/Download/21014040_9_Fizik_KTT.pdf"),
    "user:tagred",
    "testtesttest"
));
```

gives this error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: View 'user' not available

```
Path path = new File(filePath).toPath();
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
```

Here, view is null.

What should I use instead?